# Updating Debezium Kafka connector for adding new table takes too long with the unknown warn

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

When I add a new table to capture by Debezium, and update my the connector, it takes too long to handle new table.
I see this warn that I suppose the problem may be in order of that:
`WARN Renaming non-whitelisted table table_name_replic to whitelisted table table_name, this can lead to schema inconsistency (io.debezium.connector.mysql.antlr.listener.RenameTableParserListener:40)`.
We are capturing more that 100 tables via Debezium and supprizingly this warn just appears on that table and makes too long to read data from history topic and add newly including table's topic.
Does this meaningful?

my connection setup:

```
{
    "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "topic.creation.default.compression.type": "snappy",
    "database.user": "...",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": "3",
    "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",
    "database.server.id": "222",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "...",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "...:9092",
    "time.precision.mode": "connect",
    "database.server.name": "...",
    "include.schema.changes": "false",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
    "database.hostname": "...",
    "database.password": "...",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
    "name": "mysql-modiseh-09",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
    "table.include.list": "...",
    "database.include.list": "...",
    "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": 100000,
    "snapshot.new.tables": "parallel",
    "database.history.kafka.recovery.attempts": 10
}
```

Eevry time I have to wait until finish, so that I can check wether topic has been created or not.